# checking value of if it's zero or not with sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a value that comes in column as bellow

```
{200;0;7713;200;43;7670;200;0;7713
```

so these value logically divided in three sections... as bellow

200;0;7713

the first digits **200** shows account ID, and the second value which is **0** shows used from that account and the third **7713** value shows remaining, and my goal here is:

if used is greater than zero then pick remaining, like in this example:

all other valued from this account is zero but the the middle one is not so in this case I want to pick value of **7670** as teh value before that is not zero.

the account ID is not fixed means sometimes it will generate 1, 2, 4 or even 4 times like bellow:

```
{200;25;6713 
{200;0;7713;200;45;9670
{200;0;7713;200;43;8670;200;0;7713
{200;0;7713;200;43;8670;200;0;7713;200;0;7713
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you talking about those multiple values in a single column?

Comment: yes each line is one column.. like {200;25;6713  this is in one column and so on

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `split_part()`

```
select (case when split_part(col, ';', 2) <> '0' then split_part(col, ';', 3)
             when split_part(col, ';', 5) <> '0' then split_part(col, ';', 6)
             when split_part(col, ';', 8) <> '0' then split_part(col, ';', 9)
             when split_part(col, ';', 11) <> '0' then split_part(col, ';', 12)
        end)
from t;
```

However, this column suggests that your data structure is broken.  You should be storing these values in a separate table.  One row with three data values (account, used, and remaining) with repeated rows for an account.